# How to create two form login in thymeleaf spring security with different mechanism authentication and role

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have created a website using spring security and now i want that if user access to the "/hi" they will be directed to the "/login" page of user if they haven't logged and with admin if they access to the "/admin" they will be directed to the "/admin/login" page. I almost done but when i login with admin and when back to the "/hi" i no longer be redirected to the "/login" page for user but i'm in the "/hi" page. How can i fix it

```
package com.teenboutique.web.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

import com.teenboutique.web.services.CustomerDetailServiceImpl;
import com.teenboutique.web.services.EmployeeDetailServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class FormLoginSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDetailServiceImpl employeeDetailServiceImpl;
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerDetailServiceImpl customerDetailServiceImpl;

    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAdminAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(employeeDetailServiceImpl);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoUserAuthenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(customerDetailServiceImpl);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
    
    @Bean
    static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration)
            throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    //This part will be for apis
    //API will get the order 1 and push all the rest filters down 
    
    @Bean   
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain filterChainAdmin(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(null)
                .securityMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/admin/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/css/**", "/admin/images/**", "/admin/fonts/**", "/admin/js/**", "/admin/scss/**", "/admin/vendors/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/uploads/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin((formLogin) -> formLogin
                        .usernameParameter("id")
                        .passwordParameter("pass")
                        .loginPage("/admin/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin").permitAll()
                        .failureUrl("/admin/login?error=true").permitAll())
                .logout((logout) -> logout.invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/login")
                        .permitAll());
        httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(daoAdminAuthenticationProvider());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    SecurityFilterChain filterChainUser(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.securityMatcher(AntPathRequestMatcher.antMatcher("/**"))
                .authorizeHttpRequests((authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests
                        .requestMatchers("/main/css/**", "/main/images/**", "/main/js/**", "/main/plugins/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/uploads/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/" ,"/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .formLogin((formLogin) -> formLogin
                        .usernameParameter("username")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/").permitAll()
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true").permitAll())
                .logout((logout) -> logout.invalidateHttpSession(true).clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .permitAll());
        httpSecurity.authenticationProvider(daoUserAuthenticationProvider());
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Fix problem that i can seperate the authentication between admin and user.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm not understanding well what you are trying to do, but it seems to me that you are mixing up authentication and authorization.

The idea would be that you don't have different logins for users and admins, but instead that the users themselves, once logged in (using all the same login) have different roles (normal user vs admin) which in turn allows them to do different things on the application.

Roles are also standard functionality of Spring Security.

Comment: Yes, i knew about it. But what i'm trying now is making that thing but in the a more different way. Let me describe more. What i'm doing now is when i logged in admin and come to the user spring will redirect me to login page of user because i haven't logged with user account. It means i can logged in two account one is admin and one is user, now maybe spring security will store two different principal is it? The same thing when i logged in user page but haven't login with admin. I have found a way to make it but it tell that i should login with one account in a time.